# How to untar every type of tar file in a directory with bash script?

Tags: bash, if-statement, tar

I'm a beginner in writing bash scripts for automating tasks, and I'm trying to untar all the tar files in one directory (there are way too many to do it by hand) for a bunch of source code files. They're all of the type *.tar.gz, *.tar.xz, or *.tar.bz2.

This is for a Linux from Scratch LFS installation I'm doing (I'm a first timer), and I'm not sure how else to automate this task other than using a bash script. The code for my little script to do this is down below.

```
#!/bin/bash
for afile in 'ls -1'; do
    if [ 'afile | grep \"\.tar\.gz\"' ];
    then
        tar -xzf afile
    elif [ 'afile | grep \"\.tar\.xz\"' ]
    then
        tar -xJf afile
    elif [ 'afile | grep \"\.tar\.xz\"' ]
    then
        tar -xjf afile
    else
        echo "Something is wrong with the program"
    fi
done;
```

I expected it to untar everything in the directory and create separate directories, but instead it exited with this error:

```
tar (child): afile: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Apparently it thinks afile is the actual file, but I don't know how to change afile to be each file that is going through my for construct. How would I write a script for this, especially since there are different types of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your script to work with minimal changes, use `$afile` whenever you want the variable's value. The dollar sign makes a variable reference; otherwise you just get the literal string `'afile'`. Also get rid of the square brackets and instead `echo` the variable to `grep`.

```
for afile in `ls -1`; do
    if echo "$afile" | grep '\.tar\.gz'
    then
        tar -xzf "$afile"
    elif echo $afile | grep '\.tar\.xz'
    then
        tar -xJf "$afile"
    elif echo "$afile" | grep '\.tar\.bz2'
    then
        tar -xjf "$afile"
    else
        echo "Something is wrong with the program"
    fi
done
```

Since you're a bash beginner, let's look at various other ways you could write the script. I'd make a couple of improvements. For one, [you shouldn't loop over `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You can get the same thing by looping over `*`. Second, `grep` is a heavyweight tool. You can do some simple string comparisons with built-in shell constructs like `[[` and `==`.

```
for afile in *; do
    if [[ "$afile" == *.tar.gz ]]; then
        tar -xzf "$afile"
    elif [[ "$afile" == *.tar.xz ]]; then
        tar -xJf "$afile"
    elif [[ "$afile" == *.tar.bz2 ]]; then
        tar -xjf "$afile"
    else
        echo "Something is wrong with the program"
    fi
done
```

Actually, this would be even nicer with a `case` statement. Let's try that. Also let's echo the error message to stderr with `>&2`. That's always a good idea.

```
for afile in *; do
    case "$afile" in
        *.tar.gz)  tar -xzf "$afile";;
        *.tar.xz)  tar -xJf "$afile";;
        *.tar.bz2) tar -xjf "$afile";;
        *) echo "Something is wrong with the program" >&2
    esac
done
```

We could even get rid of the error message if we just list the three types of files we want to loop over. Then there's no way to hit the else case.

```
for afile in *.tar.{gz,xz,bz2}; do
    case "$afile" in
        *.tar.gz)  tar -xzf "$afile";;
        *.tar.xz)  tar -xJf "$afile";;
        *.tar.bz2) tar -xjf "$afile";;
    esac
done
```

Or a completely different way to do it: use `find` to find all the files and its `-exec` action to call a command for each file it finds. Here `{}` is a placeholder for the files it finds.

```
find . -name '*.tar.gz'  -exec tar -xzf {} \;
find . -name '*.tar.xz'  -exec tar -xJf {} \;
find . -name '*.tar.bz2' -exec tar -xjf {} \;
```

Comment: The `for afile in *.tar.{gz,xz,bz2}` version has a potential problem: it'll run the loop with the unexpanded wildcard for any extensions that don't match any files. For example, if there are no .tar.xz files, it'll run with `afile="*.tar.xz"`. To avoid this, you can set `nullglob` (with `shopt -s nullglob`) before the loop (and unset it with `shopt -u nullglob` afterward, to avoid unexpected side effects).

Comment: `*` in an empty directory has the same problem.